# How to print arrays into one array in JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript

I am facing a difficulty to print arrays when I call `makeArrays()` function. Can anyone help me out please?

```
var arr =[10,11,12,13];

    var arr2= [];
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        if(i>3){
          return arr2[i];
        } else {
            i= i+1;
           arr2.push(arr.slice(0,4));
        }
    }


console.log(makeArrays(arr));
```

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: What is `row`? ?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I just editd my code. Please check now.

Comment: `for(var i=0; i<row.length; i++)` What is `row`?

Comment: What if the input is [1,2,5,7,8,12]? What would be the output then? (If you *always* want the same result, there is no need for a function, then you just hard-code the result).

Comment: @NinaScholz I want to print [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]] like this when use console.log(makeArrays(arr));

Comment: @CertainPerformance I have edited my code. Can u please check and help me out. Many Thanks..

Comment: `const makeArrays = arr => Array.from(arr, () => [...arr])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you do not need the condition to get the expected result here. Simply push the sliced array in each iteration.

You can try the following way:

```js
var arr =[1,2,3,4];

function makeArrays(arr) {
  var arr2= [];
  for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){ 
    arr2.push(arr.slice());
  }
  return arr2;
}

console.log(makeArrays(arr));
```